# visualizing batch_norm parameters in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

My current NN model is giving some anomalous results when I change batch norm specific hyper parameters. I'd like to see the distribution of the batch norm parameters *beta* and *gamma* over time to make sure that batch norm isn't doing something weird.

Visualizing learned weights or biases is easiest to do with tensorboard, but I'm not sure how to do that with *beta* and *gamma* since they're defined and managed within `tf.layers.batch_normalization` or `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`.

Is there a simple way to reference *beta* and *gamma* and put them in a histogram summary without having to write my own version of batch norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

building a summary for them is still a chore, but this is what I've come up with for accessing `gamma` and `beta`:

```
def batch_norm(self, x_in):
    with tf.variable_scope('batch_norm'):
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(  x_in,
                                            momentum = self.bn_decay,
                                            epsilon = self.bn_epsilon,
                                            training = self.is_training)

        gamma =  tf.trainable_variables(tf.get_variable_scope().name)[0]
        beta = tf.trainable_variables(tf.get_variable_scope().name)[1]

        return x
```

what `tf.trainable_variables(tf.get_variable_scope().name)` does is return all variables within the current scope in the form of a list. In this case there are two variables, the 0th is `gamma` and the 1st is `beta` but that may change with a different implementation.

if you need the specific names use:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables(tf.get_variable_scope().name):
    print(var.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you need not only access to the `beta` and `gamma` values but also control over how they are used you could `False` `center` and `scale` from `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` and define your own scale and offset functionality. Like so:

```
def batch_norm(self, x, name = 'batch_norm'):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(  x,
                                            momentum = .99,
                                            epsilon = .0001,
                                            center = False,
                                            scale = False,
                                            training = self.is_training)

        gamma = tf.get_variable(
            name = 'gamma',
            shape = x.get_shape()[-1],
            initializer = tf.ones_initializer())
        beta = tf.get_variable(
            name = 'beta',
            shape = x.get_shape()[-1],
            initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

        x = gamma*x + beta

        return x
```